# edit xml as text file using R or Python

Tags: xml, r

I have an xml and i would like to create a script that will remove portions of it and only keep the portion bounded by . I have R, Python and Ruby.  Would you know how I can do this?  I would appreciate code suggestion as my coding skills are rather limited :D  The xml is somewhat like below:

```
<xml><sometag><somemoretag></somemoretag></sometag><records><somedetails></somedetails><somedetails2></somedetails2></records>
```

i want the results to be:

```
<xml><records><somedetails></somedetails><somedetails2></somedetails2></records>
```

thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this problem.  There may be more elegant ways of dealing with it, but as R is my preferred, I did:

```
require('XML')
a <- toString.XMLNode(xmlObject)
b <- gsub(oldString, newString, a, perl=TRUE)
c <- xmlTreeParse(b)
```

`toString.XMLNode` turns the XML to a string.  `gsub` uses regular expressions to replace `oldString` with `newString`.  Then `xmlTreeParse` turns `b` back into an XML object.

EDITS BELOW: I did not read your question correctly.  The above will help you alter your XML in very customized ways.  But in your case it's far easier to turn your XML into a tree and navigate the tree.

```
require('XML')
#Note that your code did not have a final </xml> -- I added that.
p <- xmlParse('<xml><sometag><somemoretag></somemoretag></sometag><records><somedetails></somedetails><somedetails2></somedetails2></records></xml>')
q <- getNodeSet(p, '/xml/records')
q
[[1]]
<records>
  <somedetails/>
  <somedetails2/>
</records> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet
```

By typing in the path of the nodes you want to get to as the second argument of `getNodeSet`, you can navigate the tree to where you want.

Comment: Thanks Tiff. I cannot install XML package for some reason. It says Description is missing (using Windows 7 and Version 2.5 of R).  One more, apologies if this sound like spoon feeding: what do I put in oldstring and newstring? Is there a way where I can delete everything between <sometag> and </sometag> as in my example above? Thanks again.

Comment: That's an old version of R.  You should update.  A good way to do this is with the installr package.  Read more here: http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/

Comment: I've also edited my answer to be more specific to your case--you don't need much customizing of your XML, just navigation.